# I want to set the logo on left and links on right but float dont work on nav tag ... why?

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I use this code fot navigation and also using bootstrap for my practice

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="fa">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>welcome to your site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/mehrlogo.png" width="120" alt=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I set logo on right or left, and the links on the other side?

By default the link and logo are near each other and float left or right didn't work - what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The `.navbar` uses `display: flex` to position its elements. Which means you can reposition or arange them by changing `flex-direction` and `justify-content` on `.navbar` but also pay attention to `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis` and left and right margins set on each immediate child of `.navbar`.

To start from left to right `flex-direction: row` (default).
Right to left: `flex-direction: row-reverse`.

In terms of rearranging the space between and around them, for any of the above, change `justify-content` to any of the `space-between` (default), `space-evenly`, `flex-end`, `flex-start`, `center`.

Here's an example with them in reverse order and evenly spaced:

```css
nav.navbar {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
div.navbar-collapse {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO HERE</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Note of caution**: A lot more properties set on either the parent or any of the children can influence their display behavior. Some of the most common:

- setting `margin: auto` on any child will steal all the positive space and give it to that particular gap, making `justify-content` seem like it's not working. It is working, but its distributing exactly `0` space. If you want to divide the free space to a few select gaps, place a `margin:auto` in each of those gaps using any adjacent element.
- setting `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` or `flex-basis` on any of the children will influence their size and therefore the resulting distribution of available space. A sub-note here would be that by default, on some responsiveness intervals `.navbar-collapse` has `flex-grow: 1` so you need to set it to `0` to be able to redistribute the free space. Otherwise there's no free space.

Comment: when i use reverse , the attribute set a distance to logo and links as i want , but when the attribute is as default the no distance between them and they are near each other , you know what im say?

Comment: As you can see, it works here. If it doesn't work in your case, ***you are using additional CSS which you have not included in your question***. There is no way anyone can help without knowing what the extra CSS is.

Comment: when use that attribute whole the things move but for now i want to set the links to right of browser and the logo is in correct place , and i didnt write any css external

Comment: @hossein, I can't hep if I can't see it. Make a [mcve] ***actually reproducing*** the issue. The code you provided does not repro what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use this:
If you want to put a link (or other elements) to the right, add **ml-auto** class to your element; and if you want to put it on left, add **mr-auto** class to your element.